# Delphi Error: "Cannot focus a disabled or invisible window"

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm getting an error when running my compiled program. I've taken every precaution I can think of to prevent the error such as enabling forms before I hide or focus them. The application shows a `DimmerForm` (grey fade overlay) and then a `NewFileForm` on top of the overlay. The `NewFileForm` does its stuff and determines the file that is to be made and creates a new `tabsheet` in the page control on the `MainForm` and shows the newly created tab sheet. All this works so far (I can break before the `NewFileForm` closes and any error occurs and see that the tab sheet has been created and shown successfully). The `NewFileForm` then closes, which is again working fine.

The error happens when anything then tries to set the focus back to the `MainForm`. Hiding the `DimmerForm`, or clicking on the `MainForm`, or setting focus to the `MainForm` through code all cause the error message to occur. Placing the code in a {`try`, `except`, `end`} doesn't prevent the error message either. I've searched every other method in the code that could possibly be triggered by the focusing of the `MainForm` and none are entered before the error occurs (so can't be causing it).

I wrote pretty much the exact same code in a previous version of my application and then decided to restructure it all from the ground up. The previous version of the application worked without a hitch with the form focusing.

Here is the code to open up the `NewFileForm`:

```
procedure TMainForm.NewFilesToolButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  ShowDimmer;
  NewFileForm.ShowModal;
  HideDimmer;

end;
```

Here is the code to show the dimmer form:

```
procedure ShowDimmer;
begin

  // Enable to prevent errors
  DimmerForm.Enabled := true;

  // Hide dimmer form and show mainform
  DimmerForm.Show;

end;
```

Here is the code to hide the dimmer form:

```
procedure HideDimmer;
begin

  // Enable to prevent errors
  DimmerForm.Enabled := true;
  MainForm.Enabled := true;

  // Hide dimmer form and show mainform
  DimmerForm.Hide;
  MainForm.SetFocus;

end;
```

Comment: Try changing your `HideDimmer` to `DimmerForm.Hide; MainForm.Show;` with nothing else. I'm pretty sure that the `MainForm.SetFocus` is the problem, but you've posted three chunks of code out of context so it's hard to be sure. (The code is not good, BTW; two free-standing procedures that manipulate visible controls are usually not a good idea. It's hard to tell you how to do it better, though; again, no context.)

Comment: I guess your problem is related to the newly created tabsheet that cannot get focus. Isolate the problem and write a simple reproducible test that can be debugged.

Comment: Yep, clearly you are attempting to focus a disabled or invisible window. The error message is clear. But we probably need a reproduction to be able to help solve it.

Comment: After you pressed Break on exception look into Call Stack panel, with the trace perhaps you'd be able to see some event handler of whatever code that tried to visualize the control last. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=exception+stack+trace+%5Bdelphi%5D
You can also enable "Use Debug DCUs" and intercept the exception within VCL internals, there you'd be able to `Evaluate` or `Inspect` which object was tried to display: `Self.ClassName` and `TComponent(Self).Name`.

Comment: The HideDimmer and ShowDimmer methods were added for debugging to try to test several things among various occasions when the DimmerForm is shown and hidden, I'll be getting rid of them once the problems solved. I did try the DimmerForm.Hide; MainForm.Show; no joy.

I believe that the issue is down to the newly created tab sheet. Removing the creation code stops the error occurring. The TTabSheet is fully created before the error occurs though which confuses me. Surely the error would happen in creation? None of its procedures are called (other than create) before the error occurs as well.

Comment: I have seen this error when trying to set focus to a control on the non-active tab of a Tab Sheet.  If you have code that working with a control on the new sheet try setting the active sheet first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally you are calling focus to something that is not yet created (on the form you are in the process of creating), try moving some of the onCreate code to onShow. Without more detail it is hard to tell what is happening but try this.

Comment: You are a genius, I was trying to focus on the DBGrid in the `onCreate` event, moving `DBGrid.SetFocus` to `onShow` solved the issue.

Comment: OnCreate and OnShow are terrible places to initialize your code. I describe in my "Delphi in all its glory" a way to do proper initialization. You can find the code also in ccAppData.pas in GitHub (free library).

Answer (score 0):

Solution given in a comment posted by [Arioch 'The](https://stackoverflow.com/users/976391/arioch-the)

> You can also enable "Use Debug DCUs" [...]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! However, this does not provide an answer to the question.You can search for similar questions, or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question, and include a link to this one to help provide context.

Comment: @toti08 It's an answer, but it had poor form. I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error is caused by some kind of activity by the database components during the Post event...
If you tried everything else you could try this quick solution: set the Datasource connected to the Dataset to NIL and then set it back once the Post event complete.

Something like this:

```
Try
    Datasource1.DataSet := NIL;

    Try
        Query1.Post;
    Except
        On E: Exception Do
        Begin
            ShowMessage('Post error!' + #13#10 + #13#10 + E.Message);
            Exit;
        End;
    End;

Finally
    Datasource1.DataSet := Query1;
End;
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, please delete it!  If you get the error in the q title while posting an edit to a dataset, there is something else wrong with your code which is causing it.  A dataset `Post` should never ever cause this error.  Rather than try a quick solution, do some proper debugging and find the real cause of your problem!

Comment: Got this error after changed fields in database to not required, but forgot to readd fields in query component